# Accuracy of Forecasting using ets() in r

Tags: r

I want measure accuracy of forecasting using MAE method by comparing the actual values with the predicted values. I am using ets() under package forecast.

```
Point Forecast    Lo 80    Hi 80    Lo 95    Hi 95
    349       14.50443 13.73768 15.27118 13.33178 15.67707
    350       14.50443 13.57620 15.43266 13.08482 15.92403
    351       14.50443 13.43881 15.57004 12.87471 16.13414
    352       14.50443 13.31713 15.69172 12.68862 16.32024
    353       14.50443 13.20673 15.80213 12.51977 16.48909
    354       14.50443 13.10493 15.90393 12.36408 16.64478
    355       14.50443 13.00998 15.99888 12.21886 16.78999
    356       14.50443 12.92064 16.08822 12.08223 16.92663
    357       14.50443 12.83601 16.17284 11.95281 17.05605
    358       14.50443 12.75541 16.25344 11.82954 17.17932
    359       14.50443 12.67831 16.33055 11.71162 17.29724
    360       14.50443 12.60427 16.40458 11.59839 17.41047
    361       14.50443 12.53296 16.47590 11.48933 17.51953
    362       14.50443 12.46409 16.54477 11.38399 17.62486
    363       14.50443 12.39741 16.61145 11.28202 17.72684
    364       14.50443 12.33273 16.67613 11.18310 17.82576
    365       14.50443 12.26987 16.73899 11.08697 17.92189
    366       14.50443 12.20868 16.80017 10.99339 18.01547
    367       14.50443 12.14904 16.85981 10.90218 18.10668
    368       14.50443 12.09083 16.91803 10.81314 18.19571
    369       14.50443 12.03394 16.97492 10.72614 18.28272
    370       14.50443 11.97829 17.03057 10.64103 18.36783
    371       14.50443 11.92379 17.08506 10.55769 18.45117
    372       14.50443 11.87039 17.13847 10.47601 18.53285
    373       14.50443 11.81800 17.19086 10.39589 18.61297
    374       14.50443 11.76657 17.24228 10.31724 18.69162
    375       14.50443 11.71606 17.29280 10.23998 18.76888
    376       14.50443 11.66640 17.34246 10.16404 18.84482
    377       14.50443 11.61756 17.39130 10.08934 18.91951
    378       14.50443 11.56949 17.43936 10.01583 18.99302
```

These are 30 predicted values, however I want to take only the forecast column but am not able to extract it.
I have tried doing it by,

```
library(forecast)
> f<-ets(st1)
> a<-predict(f,30)
> a$Forecast
```

It shows NULL. Can You please help me out. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

`a[["Point Forecast"]]` might do it since "Point Forecast" seems to be the column name, or <strike>`a[[1]]` since it is the first</strike> `a[[2]]` since it is the second column.

Comment: Thank you, a[[2]] worked, it is the second column. thanks a lot